# Bitwise NOT Operator in D

Tags: bitwise-operators, d

Is there a bitwise NOT operator included in D2? If not, what's an alternative? Will `!` just work? I'm guessing it won't because if it did `!1` would equal true, which it doesn't.

Comment: I think bitwise is `~`. Logical is `!`.

Comment: Since D keeps retains all C operators, `~` should be it.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson That seems to be working indeed. It's not mentioned on the documentation however: http://dlang.org/expression.html

Comment: [ComplementExpression](http://dlang.org/expression.html#ComplementExpression) seems to be it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the comments:

The correct way to do it is using the [Complement Expression](http://dlang.org/expression.html#ComplementExpression). (`~1` as opposed to `!1`)